# Library Management System. Borrowing book boolean

Tags: c#

So I'm currently trying to get the grips of c# as a beginner and I'm building a library management system. I've added everything I need, however, I want to add a functionality feature of it where you can borrow a book and it would mark it as borrowed and no one else would be able to borrow it until they return it. I tried adding a boolean for it to mark a book as borrowed, but it doesn't seem to mark a book as borrowed and instead lets me run the borrowing function endless times.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Bibliotek
{
    //Definerar klassen Book
    class Book
    {
        public boolean IsBorrowed
        { get; set; }
        public string Author
        { get; set; }
        public string Title
        { get; set; }

    }
    class Program
    {
        static List<Book> BookList = new List<Book>();
        static Book Book = new Book();


        //Menyn och startsidan till programmet
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader("Bookfil.txt"))
            {
                string s;
                while ((s = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Book Book = new Book();
                    string[] BookData = s.Split(',');
                    Book.Author = BookData[0];
                    Book.Title = BookData[1];
                    BookList.Add(Book);
                }
                readFile.Close();
            }
 bool stäng = true;
                while (stäng)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\nVälkommen till biblioteket!\n" +
                    "\n1)Lägg till Bok\n" +
                    "2)Radera Bok\n" +
                    "3)Leta efter Bok\n" +
                    "4)Låna Bok\n" +
                    "5)Lämna tillbaks Bok\n" +
                    "6)Stäng program\n\n");

                    int val = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (val == 1)
                    {
                        AddBook();
                    }
                    else if (val == 2)
                    {
                        RemoveBook();
                    }
                    else if (val == 3)
                    {
                        SearchBook();
                    }
                    else if (val == 4)
                    {
                        BorrowBook();
                    }
                    else if (val == 5)
                    {
                        ReturnBook();
                    }
                    else if (val == 6)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Tack!");
                        stäng = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid option\nFörsök igen! ");
                    }
                }
```

```
        public static void BorrowBook()
        {
            Console.Write("Mata in en Author eller Booktitel: ");
            string borrow = Console.ReadLine();
            foreach (Book b in BookList)
            {
                if (b.Title.Equals(borrow))
                {
                    if (b.IsBorrowed == true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Book is already taken");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(b.Author + ":" + b.Title);
                        b.IsBorrowed = true;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: It looks like this code should work (PS it looks like you forgot to show the `IsBorrowed` property in the `Book` class). Please try debugging it, put breakpoints, examine variables, and see how the flow goes. If that still leaves you with questions, then [edit] the question and provide details on exactly what is happening.

Comment: where you call BorrowBook() and did you save edited data in to file again?

Comment: We can't see how you are calling borrowBook so it's hard to know if there's a logical mistake in that area.

Comment: @MuhammadUsamaAlam I call the BorrowBook() further down in the code, it's not visible in the parts here. But that part works as it runs BorrowBook() correctly, it just never marks a book as borrowed. So I'm assuming it doesn't save it to file again.

Comment: call the same function with the same parameter twice to check and confirm that message

Comment: You never save anything to a file, as far as we can see. All you do is update the IsBorrowed value in memory. So it will remember it for the lifetime of the program, but not when you stop the program and restart it. From your description it's unclear if you call borrowBook multiple times within one run of the program, or if you are restarting it each time. You would be far better with a simple database such as SqLite or SQL server localdb for this purpose, rather than a text file. Text file is ok for reading from, but becomes a pain when you need to write back to a specific location within it.

Comment: and share your complete Static Void Method (SVM)

Comment: Ok thanks for the update. So presumably you're calling BorrowBook multiple times within the same run of the program, without restarting it? If so, then it looks like it should work. After you enter the book you want, does it then print the author and title via the `Console.WriteLine(b.Author + ":" + b.Title);`  line? If so, then it should be setting the book as borrowed. Use the visual studio debugger to check variable values along your route, and see if it then recognises it the next time.

Comment: P.S. As an aside, you probably don't need a loop to identify your book - Linq has Find() and Where() and First() functions, all of which can potentially find an item in your list directly, without looping.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the help, I solved it. I'm not too used to LINQ, so I'm not sure how those work. I'll give it a look though!

Comment: That's great. If you solved it, please add your solution below, for the benefit of others (and for your benefit, it you get upvotes for it). Answering your own question is perfectly allowed and encouraged :-)